# Best way to combine dataframes (with missing & new data): merge vs combine_first vs fillna

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I searched a lot but couldn't find an answer about which way (merge vs combine_first vs fillna+append) would be the best/most efficient/most robust way to combine two dataframes that are complementary (but the data in the first should not be overriden).

```
import pandas as pd

test1 = {'name': ['name a','name b','name c','name d', 'name e'],
        'val1': [1,1,1,1,1], 
        'val2': [None,None,None,None,None], 
        'val3': [4,4,4,None,None],
        'val4': [5,5,5,5,5]}   
d1=pd.DataFrame(test1)

test2 = {'name': ['name a','name c','name b','name e', 'name f'],
        'val1': [1,2,3,3,4],
        'val3': [3,3,None,3,None],
        'val2': [2,2,3,5,None],
        'val5': [6,6,6,6,6]}  
d2=pd.DataFrame(test2)

d1.set_index('name', inplace=True)
d2.set_index('name', inplace=True)

# V1
d3=d1.combine_first(d2)
d3.reset_index('name', inplace=True)

# V2
adddf=d2[~d2.index.isin(d1.index)]   
d4=d1.append(adddf)
d4=d4.fillna(d2) 

# V3
d5 = pd.merge(left=d1, right=d2, left_on='name', right_on='name', suffixes=('','_x'), how='outer') 
d5['val1'].fillna(d5['val1_x'], inplace=True)      
d5['val2'].fillna(d5['val2_x'], inplace=True)    
d5['val3'].fillna(d5['val3_x'], inplace=True)         
d5.drop(d5.filter(regex='_x$').columns.tolist(),axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Background:
I have a set of data points that I want to complete (with data from multiple sources, each source is used to add new rows or fill in missing columns of existing data but should not override existing data).

Each row has one identifier(name) column, there will/should not be any duplicates, if a source has conflicting data, I want to keep the current (as long as there already is data, if not fill in the new).

From my research all three functions work equally well (and with small dataframes there were no big time differences, could change with bigger dfs, didn't test) and where able to handle the multiple edge cases I introduced:

- column order switched in df2 (name c, name b)
- row order switched in df2 (val3,val2)
- different data in df2 that should not replace data in df1
- missing data in df1 and df2

What should happen:

- a: 1,nan,4,5 -> 1,2,4(not 3),5,6
- b: 1,nan,4,5 -> 1,3(not 2),4,5,6
- c: 1,nan,4,5 -> 1(not2/3,)2(not 3),4,5,6
- d: 1,n,n,5 -> 1,n,n,5,n(not6)
- e: ->1(not 3),5,3,5,6
- f: ->4,n,n,n,6

Which one would you prefer or is there an even better way for what I'm trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
x = d1.merge(d2, on="name", how="outer", suffixes=("", "_x"))

for c in d1.columns:
    if c + "_x" not in x.columns:
        continue
    x[[c, c + "_x"]] = x[[c, c + "_x"]].transform(sorted, key=pd.isna, axis=1)

print(x[d1.columns.union(d2.columns)])
```

Prints:

```
     name  val1  val2  val3  val4  val5
0  name a   1.0   2.0   4.0   5.0   6.0
1  name b   1.0   3.0   4.0   5.0   6.0
2  name c   1.0   2.0   4.0   5.0   6.0
3  name d   1.0   NaN   NaN   5.0   NaN
4  name e   1.0   5.0   3.0   5.0   6.0
5  name f   4.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   6.0
```